# I don't know how to solve "local reference table overflow" error in android JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am experiencing a local reference overflow error when running my algorithm written in JNI. The code works fine up to 2000-3000 iterations, but after that, it crashes with the error message "local reference table overflow". I suspect there might be a memory leak somewhere in the code, but I can't seem to find it.

Here is the code I'm using:

```cpp
#include <valarray>
#include <map>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <thread>
#include <time.h>


#define COULOMB 4800.0
#define DISTANCE 3200
#define GRAVITY 0.04
#define BOUNCE 0.06
#define ATTENUATION 0.4

jboolean op = true;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_networkmemo_algorithm_ForcedGraphAlgorithm_operate(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jobject nodes,
        jobject edges,
        jobject nodeId2Index
) {
    jclass com_example_composableoptimizing_Node = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("com/example/networkmemo/db/Node")));
    jmethodID node_set_dx = env ->GetMethodID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "setDx", "(D)V");
    jmethodID node_set_dy = env ->GetMethodID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "setDy", "(D)V");
    jmethodID node_set_x = env ->GetMethodID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "setX", "(D)V");
    jmethodID node_set_y = env ->GetMethodID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "setY", "(D)V");

    jfieldID node_dx_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "dx", "D");
    jfieldID node_dy_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "dy", "D");
    jfieldID node_x_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "x", "D");
    jfieldID node_y_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "y", "D");
    jfieldID node_size_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node, "size", "D");

    jclass com_example_composableoptimizing_Edge = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("com/example/networkmemo/db/Edge")));
    jfieldID edge_node1_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Edge, "node1", "J");
    jfieldID edge_node2_field = env ->GetFieldID(com_example_composableoptimizing_Edge, "node2", "J");

    jclass java_util_ArrayList = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList")));
    jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_size = env ->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "size", "()I");
    jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_get = env ->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "get","(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_set = env ->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "set", "(ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    jclass java_util_HashMap = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("java/util/HashMap")));
    jmethodID java_util_HashMap_get = env ->GetMethodID(java_util_HashMap, "get","(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    jclass java_lang_Integer = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("java/lang/Integer")));
    jmethodID java_lang_Integer_parseInt = env ->GetStaticMethodID(java_lang_Integer, "parseInt", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I");
    // jmethodID java_lang_Integer_valueOf = env ->GetStaticMethodID(java_lang_Integer, "valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");

    jclass java_lang_Long = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("java/lang/Long")));
    // jmethodID java_lang_Long_parseLong = env ->GetStaticMethodID(java_lang_Long, "parseLong", "(Ljava/lang/String;)J");
    jmethodID java_lang_Long_valueOf = env ->GetStaticMethodID(java_lang_Long, "valueOf", "(J)Ljava/lang/Long;");

    jclass java_lang_Double = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("java/lang/Double")));
    // jmethodID java_lang_Double_valueOf = env ->GetStaticMethodID(java_lang_Double, "valueOf", "(D)Ljava/lang/Double;");

    jclass java_lang_Object = static_cast<jclass>(env ->NewGlobalRef(env ->FindClass("java/lang/Object")));
    jmethodID java_lang_Object_toString = env ->GetMethodID(java_lang_Object, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    jint nodeLen = env ->CallIntMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_size);
    jint edgeLen = env ->CallIntMethod(edges, java_util_ArrayList_size);

    jobject* ithNode = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jobject* jthNode = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jobject* jthEdge = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jobject* jthNode1Object = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jobject* jthNode2Object = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jobject* jthNode1IndexObject = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jobject* jthNode2IndexObject = (jobject*) malloc(4);
    jstring* jthNode1IndexString = (jstring*) malloc(4);
    jstring* jthNode2IndexString = (jstring*) malloc(4);
    jobject* targetNode = (jobject*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* ithX = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* ithY = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* ithDx = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* ithDy = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* ithSize = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* fx = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* fy = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* jthX = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* jthY = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* distX = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* distY = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* rsq = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* rsqRound = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* coulombDistX = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* coulombDistY = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* coulombDistRoundX = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* coulombDistRoundY = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* distXC = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* distYC = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jlong* jthNode1 = (jlong*) malloc(4);
    jlong* jthNode2 = (jlong*) malloc(4);

    jint* jthNode1Index = (jint*) malloc(4);
    jint* jthNode2Index = (jint*) malloc(4);

    jdouble* targetNodeX = (jdouble*) malloc(4);
    jdouble* targetNodeY = (jdouble*) malloc(4);

    jint* i = (jint*) malloc(4);
    jint* j = (jint*) malloc(4);

    clock_t start, end, result;

    while(op) {

        start = clock();

        for (*i = 0; *i < nodeLen; (*i)++) {
            *ithNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get, *i);
            *ithX = env->GetDoubleField(*ithNode, node_x_field);
            *ithY = env->GetDoubleField(*ithNode, node_y_field);
            *ithDx = env->GetDoubleField(*ithNode, node_dx_field);
            *ithDy = env->GetDoubleField(*ithNode, node_dy_field);
            *ithSize = env->GetDoubleField(*ithNode, node_size_field);

            *fx = 0.0;
            *fy = 0.0;

            for (*j = 0; *j < nodeLen; (*j)++) {
                *jthNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get, *j);
                *jthX = env->GetDoubleField(*jthNode, node_x_field);
                *jthY = env->GetDoubleField(*jthNode, node_y_field);

                *distX = (*ithX + *ithSize / 2) - (*jthX + *ithSize / 2);
                *distY = (*ithY + *ithSize / 2) - (*jthY + *ithSize / 2);
                *rsq = *distX * *distX + *distY * *distY;
                *rsqRound = (jint) *rsq * 100;
                *rsq = (jdouble) (*rsqRound / 100);

                *coulombDistX = COULOMB * *distX;
                *coulombDistY = COULOMB * *distY;
                *coulombDistRoundX = (jint) *coulombDistX * 100;
                *coulombDistRoundY = (jint) *coulombDistY * 100;
                *coulombDistX = (jdouble) (*coulombDistRoundX / 100);
                *coulombDistY = (jdouble) (*coulombDistRoundY / 100);

                if (*rsq != 0.0 && sqrt(*rsq) < DISTANCE) {
                    *fx += *coulombDistX / *rsq;
                    *fy += *coulombDistY / *rsq;
                }
            }

            *distXC = -1 * (*ithX + *ithSize / 2);
            *distYC = -1 * (*ithY + *ithSize / 2);
            *fx += GRAVITY * *distXC;
            *fy += GRAVITY * *distYC;

            for (*j = 0; *j < edgeLen; (*j)++) {

                *jthEdge = env->CallObjectMethod(edges, java_util_ArrayList_get, *j);
                *jthNode1 = env->GetLongField(*jthEdge, edge_node1_field);
                *jthNode2 = env->GetLongField(*jthEdge, edge_node2_field);

                *jthNode1Object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(java_lang_Long,
                                                              java_lang_Long_valueOf, *jthNode1);
                *jthNode2Object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(java_lang_Long,
                                                              java_lang_Long_valueOf, *jthNode2);

                *jthNode1IndexObject = env->CallObjectMethod(nodeId2Index, java_util_HashMap_get,
                                                             *jthNode1Object);
                *jthNode2IndexObject = env->CallObjectMethod(nodeId2Index, java_util_HashMap_get,
                                                             *jthNode2Object);

                *jthNode1IndexString = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(
                        *jthNode1IndexObject, java_lang_Object_toString));
                *jthNode2IndexString = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(
                        *jthNode2IndexObject, java_lang_Object_toString));

                *jthNode1Index = env->CallStaticIntMethod(java_lang_Integer,
                                                              java_lang_Integer_parseInt,
                                                              *jthNode1IndexString);
                *jthNode2Index = env->CallStaticIntMethod(java_lang_Integer,
                                                              java_lang_Integer_parseInt,
                                                              *jthNode2IndexString);

                *distX = 0.0;
                *distY = 0.0;
                if (*i == *jthNode1Index) {
                    *targetNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get,
                                                        *jthNode2Index);
                    *targetNodeX = env->GetDoubleField(*targetNode, node_x_field);
                    *targetNodeY = env->GetDoubleField(*targetNode, node_y_field);

                    *distX = *targetNodeX - *ithX;
                    *distY = *targetNodeY - *ithY;
                } else if (*i == *jthNode2Index) {
                    *targetNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get,
                                                        *jthNode1Index);
                    *targetNodeX = env->GetDoubleField(*targetNode, node_x_field);
                    *targetNodeY = env->GetDoubleField(*targetNode, node_y_field);

                    *distX = *targetNodeX - *ithX;
                    *distY = *targetNodeY - *ithY;
                }

                *fx += BOUNCE * *distX;
                *fy += BOUNCE * *distY;
            }

            *ithDx = (*ithDx + *fx) * ATTENUATION;
            *ithDy = (*ithDy + *fy) * ATTENUATION;

            env->CallVoidMethod(*ithNode, node_set_dx, *ithDx);
            env->CallVoidMethod(*ithNode, node_set_dy, *ithDy);
            env->CallVoidMethod(*ithNode, node_set_x, *ithX + *ithDx);
            env->CallVoidMethod(*ithNode, node_set_y, *ithY + *ithDy);

            env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_set, *i, *ithNode);
        }
        end = clock();
        result = end - start;
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "APPNAME", "%ld", result);
        if(result < 30) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30 - result));
        }
    }

    free(ithNode);
    free(jthNode);
    free(jthEdge);
    free(jthNode1Object);
    free(jthNode2Object);
    free(jthNode1IndexObject);
    free(jthNode2IndexObject);
    free(jthNode1IndexString);
    free(jthNode2IndexString);
    free(targetNode);

    free(ithX);
    free(ithY);
    free(ithDx);
    free(ithDy);
    free(ithSize);

    free(fx);
    free(fy);
    free(jthX);
    free(jthY);
    free(distX);
    free(distY);

    free(rsq);
    free(rsqRound);
    free(coulombDistX);
    free(coulombDistY);
    free(coulombDistRoundX);
    free(coulombDistRoundY);

    free(distXC);
    free(distYC);
    free(jthNode1);
    free(jthNode2);
    free(jthNode1Index);
    free(jthNode2Index);
    free(targetNodeX);
    free(targetNodeY);

    free(i);
    free(j);

    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(com_example_composableoptimizing_Node);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(com_example_composableoptimizing_Edge);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(java_util_ArrayList);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(java_util_HashMap);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(java_lang_Integer);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(java_lang_Long);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(java_lang_Double);
    env ->DeleteGlobalRef(java_lang_Object);
}
```

I would appreciate any help in identifying the cause of the memory leak and resolving the local reference overflow error.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

There is an error message.

```
2024-03-18 17:31:27.129 25373-25397 ple.networkmem          com.example.networkmemo              A  jni_env_ext-inl.h:32] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=8388608)
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32] local reference table dump:
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]   Last 10 entries (of 8388608):
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388607: 0x134024d8 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388606: 0x13402458 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388605: 0x134023d8 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388604: 0x13402358 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388603: 0x134022d8 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388602: 0x13402258 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388601: 0x134021d8 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388600: 0x13402158 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388599: 0x134020d8 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388598: 0x13402058 com.example.networkmemo.db.Node
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]   Summary:
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]     8388599 of com.example.networkmemo.db.Node (30 unique instances)
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]         8 of java.lang.Class (8 unique instances)
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]         1 of kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker
                                                                                                    jni_env_ext-inl.h:32]  Resizing failed: Requested size exceeds maximum: 16777216
2024-03-18 17:31:27.172 25373-25397 ple.networkmem          com.example.networkmemo              A  runtime.cc:669] Runtime aborting...
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669] All threads:
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669] DALVIK THREADS (23):
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669] "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2" prio=5 tid=22 Runnable
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669]   | group="" sCount=0 ucsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13401590 self=0xb4000070373bc520
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669]   | sysTid=25397 nice=0 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0x6e492afcb0
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669]   | state=R schedstat=( 7673982074 795384995 686 ) utm=664 stm=102 core=2 HZ=100
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:669]   | stack=0x6e491ac000-0x6e491ae000 stackSize=1039KB
```

Thank you for your attention. The reason I allocated all of them is because I tried various things to solve the error, but it didn't work...

Comment: Please share full error message.

Comment: Why are you defining all your local variables as malloced pointers? Just use plain variables, it will make your code much more readable.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, every object reference you create in a loop, either by allocating, calling `GetObjectField` or doing `CallObjectMethod` should be passed to `env->DeleteLocalRef` when you no longer need it, usually at the end of the loop iteration.

Comment: Also, you only need global references if you are going to keep `jobject`s alive *outside* of the current function invocation.

Comment: That’s what `PushLocalFrame()`is for, and its mate `PopLocalFrame()`. Do you really need all these references at the same time? And do you really need all these `malloc()`s?

Comment: And why are you creating and releasing global references inside the same method? Don’t do that. Stick to local references locally.

Comment: The `malloc(4)`s should all be `malloc(sizeof double*)`, or indeed `new double *`, but as a matter of fact all those variables should be local `double`s that don't need dynamic memory allocation at all. Very strange code here. Get rid of that; get rid of the `GlobalReferences`, and use `Push/PopLocalFrame()` to get the number of local reference slots that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the JVM invokes a native function, it allocates a table for local object references. These are needed to inform the garbage collector which objects your native code still references. At the end of your function these references are released and the GC can potentially clean up after you.

This local reference table is not infinitely large and you ran into its limits. You thus need to do some housekeeping yourself by using `DeleteLocalRef`. This tells the JVM you are done with an object and it can reuse the slot for another object reference.

Stripping your code down to just the object allocations, you need to add a `DeleteLocalRef` every time you allocate an object or retrieve an object reference inside a loop:

```
for (*i = 0; *i < nodeLen; (*i)++) {
        *ithNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get, *i);

        /* ... */

        for (*j = 0; *j < nodeLen; (*j)++) {
                *jthNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get, *j);

                /* ... */
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode);
        }

        for (*j = 0; *j < edgeLen; (*j)++) {

                *jthEdge = env->CallObjectMethod(edges, java_util_ArrayList_get, *j);

                *jthNode1Object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(java_lang_Long, java_lang_Long_valueOf, *jthNode1);
                *jthNode2Object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(java_lang_Long, java_lang_Long_valueOf, *jthNode2);

                *jthNode1IndexObject = env->CallObjectMethod(nodeId2Index, java_util_HashMap_get, *jthNode1Object);
                *jthNode2IndexObject = env->CallObjectMethod(nodeId2Index, java_util_HashMap_get, *jthNode2Object);

                *jthNode1IndexString = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod( *jthNode1IndexObject, java_lang_Object_toString));
                *jthNode2IndexString = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod( *jthNode2IndexObject, java_lang_Object_toString));

                /* ... */
                if (*i == *jthNode1Index) {
                        *targetNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get, *jthNode2Index);
                        /* ... */
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(*targetNode);
                } else if (*i == *jthNode2Index) {
                        *targetNode = env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_get, *jthNode1Index);
                        /* ... */
                        env->DeleteLocalRef(*targetNode);
                }

                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthEdge);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode1Object);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode2Object);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode1IndexObject);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode2IndexObject);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode1IndexString);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(*jthNode2IndexString);
        }

        env->CallObjectMethod(nodes, java_util_ArrayList_set, *i, *ithNode);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(*ithNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to get my code working properly. I really appreciate your assistance. I'm curious about something. Even though I allocate references in memory and reuse them continuously, why do I still run into the table capacity limit? Is the object reference table allocated by CallObjectMethod, as you mentioned, different from the memory I'm thinking of?

Comment: The local reference table is a separate piece of memory that is managed by the JVM. what you do with `malloc/free` is just the native heap and has nothing to do with that.

Comment: and every call to, say, `CallObjectMethod` puts a reference in a fresh slot. Your `jobject` variable is simply an index into the local reference table, so if you overwrite, say, `targetNode` with a new index, you lose the ability to free the original reference!